# Add selected text to textbox with additional info

Tags: javascript, html

What I want - A button that (onclick) adds the selected text to a textbox (with the name of "body"). I would like it to be prefixed with a linebreak and greater than sign, and at the end two linebreaks/a paragraph.

My current code:

```
function
addtext() {
var newtext = '\uA' '\u3E' document.getSelection() '\uA';
this.email.comments.value += newtext;
location.href="#emailme"}
```

Basically, after selecting text and clicking the button, add the selected text to the form with a few changes. What actually happens is absolutely nothing.

Notes: NO JQUERY. JQuery answers will be ignored. Pure JS only.

Comment: Did you log what document.getSelection returns in your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("text-box"); // replace the id by your text box identifier

var addTextButton = document.getElementById("add-text-button"); // replace the id by your button identifier

function addText() {
    // \u000a is escape sequence for line feed
    var newText = '\u000a>' + document.getSelection().anchorNode.textContent + '\u000a\u000a';
    // add any extra data to new text here like newText += extraData
    textBox.value += newText;
}

addTextButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addText();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working. I've uploaded it to https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fr4bgphk2pjga7z/form20.html for further testing.
Google Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (Official Build) m (32-bit)
Revision 3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311-refs/branch-heads/2454@{#502}
OS Windows 
Blink 537.36 (@3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311)
JavaScript V8 4.5.103.35

Comment: move your `script` tag to the bottom of the page just before closing the `body` tag, the `add-text-button` element is not loaded yet when the script is run so event handler is not attached or if there is some reason you can't do that, put the scripts content in a function and attach that to the `onload` event like this `window.onload=functionName`

Comment: Ok, after further testing it is not adding the text, just deleting previous text. Chrome only issue?

Comment: no it's not just chrome, if you want it to keep the previous text in the text box replace `textbox.value = newText` with `textbox.value += newText`... `=` replaces the previous value but `+=` just appends.